# Method not found paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, will-paginate

I get

```
undefined method `photo' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000102a8a7c0>
```

error while I'm trying to display image on my page. I'm using paperclip for uploading the files and will_paginate.

Here is the content of Admin::Image model

```
class Admin::Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :added_on, :title, :photo

  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :photo

  self.per_page = 15

  has_attached_file :photo
end
```

Here is the content of Image controller

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @data = Admin::Image.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

And the view

```
<%= image_tag @data.photo.url %>
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you are assigning a collection of Admin::Image objects to @data instance variable (BTW why not call it @images), and in the view you are trying to call a 'photo' method on entire collection, while 'photo' method is available in Admin::Image object.

Answer (score 0):

Cthulhu is right, what you are missing is iterating over the collection:

```
<% @data.each do |datum| %>
  <%= image_tag datum.photo.url %>
<% end %>
```